# Использование словаря с двойными значениями для записи короткого значения поля БД в Django

Tags: django, model

Подскажите, как мне правильно сформировать элементы этого словаря для записи в поле модели Django кратких значений и вывода соответствующих читаемых с помощью метода `get_valuta_display()`?

**Словарь для модели** **`Cash`**:

```
class Cash(models.Model):
    MONEY = {
    'dollar': ('D', 'Доллар'),
      'rubl': ('R', 'Рубль'),
      'euro': ('E', 'Евро'),
    }
    valuta =  models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=MONEY)
```

Django ругается на такой словарь и требует два значения.

**Но наличие ключа здесь необходимо.**

Answer (score 0):

У тебя `max_length=1`,а все значения для базы больше 1 символа. Так же не уверен, что можно создавать варианты ответа словарём, в [документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/) видел только список и кортежи. Попробуй вот так:

```
class Cash(models.Model):
    MONEY = [
    ('D', ('dollar', 'Доллар')),
      ('R', ('rubl', 'Рубль')),
      ('E', ('euro', 'Евро')),
    ]
    valuta =  models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=MONEY)
```

Такой список точно должен подходить под варианты ответа. Если что-то не получится, попробуй сделать по аналогии с документацией